# r - Estimate selection-unbiased allele frequencies with linear regression systems

Tags: r, constraints, linear-regression, linear-equation

I have a few data sets consisting of frequencies for `i` distinct alleles/SNPs of some populations. Additionally I recorded some factors that are suspicious for having changed the frequencies of these alleles within the populations in the past due to their selectional effect. It is assumed that the selection impact can be described in the form of a simple linear regression for every selection factor.

Now I'd like to estimate how the allele frequencies are expected to be under identical selectional forces (thus, I set `selection=1`). These new allele frequencies `a'_i` are derived as

```
a'_i = a_i - function[a_i|selection=1]
```

with the current frequency `a_i` of the allele `i` of a population and `function[a_i|selection=1]` as the estimated allele frequency under the absence of selectional forces.

However, there are some constraints for the whole process:

1. The minimal values of `a'_i` allowed is 0.
2. The sum of all allele frequencies `a'_i` has to be 1.

Usually I'd solve this problem by applying multiple linear regressions. But then the constraints are not fulfilled ...

Any idea how to approach this analysis with constraints (maybe using linear equation/regression systems or structural equation modelling)?

[Here](http://www.biostudies.de/images/test.csv) is an example data set containing allele frequencies for the ABO major allele groups (p, q, r) as well as the selection variables (x, y, z).

Although this example file only contains 3 alleles and 3 influential variables, all my data sets contain up to ~1050 alleles/SNPs and always 8 selection variables that may have (but don't have to) an impact on the allele frequencies ...

Many thanks in advance for ideas, code snippets and hints!